# FactoryGirl, rails, cucumber: Make association with multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

OK, the factoryGirl pages at thoughtbot are very helpful, but I'm doing something wrong. In an earlier iteration of a basic feature I made two records and forced the association per the abbreviated example below:

```
 Given /^a price for corn has already been entered$/ do
   corn = Commodity.create!(name: "Corn", wholesale_unit: "ton")
   Price.create!(commodity: corn, retail_high: "19")
 end
```

Now I want to make two prices so that I can test the average in cucumber to assure that both are being pulled. I have easily created factories for the above per Nash's suggestion.

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :commodity do 
     name 'Corn'
     wholesale_unit 'ton'
   end

   factory :price do 
     sequence(:retail_high) { |n| '19#{n}' }
     commodity
   end
 end
```

In my updated step.rb file, I try to create the conditions that work in the first iteration but have two records:

```
 Given /^there are prices entered$/ do 
   Factory(:commodity)
   Factory(:price) do
     sequence(:retail_high)
   end
 end
```

So my real problem is that I'm unable to get to first base because when I use pry to see if a record is being created, I get a Price = nil. Same with commodity. There are so many attributes that getting factory to work would really help. Updating the above to Nash' examples below show the correct first record, but the second record is a repeat of the first. Following are my model, relevant controller and schema. thanx for hanging in, sam

commodity.rb:

```
 class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :prices
 end
```

price.rb:

```
 class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commodity
 end
```

commodities_controller.rb:

```
  class CommoditiesController < ApplicationController
    def show
    @commodity = Commodity.find(params[:id])
   end
```

relevant schema.rb:

```
   create_table "commodities", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.string   "wholesale_unit"
   t.string   "retail_unit"
   t.string   "farm_gate_unit"
   t.string   "delivered_unit"
   t.string   "receipt_unit"
     end

  create_table "prices", :force => true do |t|
   t.date     "date"
   t.string   "price_type"
   t.string   "quality"
   t.string   "farm_gate_unit"
   t.decimal  "farm_gate_high"
   t.decimal  "farm_gate_low"
   t.string   "delivered_unit"
   t.decimal  "delivered_high"
   t.decimal  "delivered_low"
   t.string   "wholesale_unit"
   t.decimal  "wholesale_high"
   t.decimal  "wholesale_low"
   t.string   "retail_unit"
   t.decimal  "retail_high"
   t.decimal  "retail_low"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "commodity_id"
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use FactoryGirl 2.

```
# factories.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :commodity do
    name 'Corn'
    wholesale_unit 'ton'
  end

  factory :price do
    retail_high { Random.new.rand(100..500) }
    commodity
  end
end

# steps.rb

Given /^there are prices entered$/ do 
  FactoryGirl.create_list(:price, 2, commodity: Factory(:commodity))   
end
```

This will give you two price objects for the same corn commodity.
If you want to fabricate two prices for different commodities, you may write:

```
Given /^there are prices entered$/ do 
  Factory(:price) # this for corn   
  Factory(:price, commodity: Factory(:commodity, name: 'Weat'))
end
```

Comment: Thx, this should work, the only thing different in my step.rb from yours is adding ->{ binding.pry }.call. My limited pry skills suggest I 'cd' into Price and 'first'. That yields the nil. '@relation' yields '[]'. Those commands worked in the past. In trying to eliminate environment variables, I pulled out other features, step.rb files, but no change. Is my binding.pry the issue?

Comment: Why do you want to test FactoryGirl with Pry? Do your tests pass without any debug tools?

Comment: They hadn't matched the expected values, so I worked backward to if cucumber created the records. In previous tests, pry could see that the record was created. The test was to click on "Corn" and see the retail_price. The error I got was that "undefined method `retail_high' for nil:NilClass (ActionView::Template::Error)". That suggests that cucumber cannot see the record linked via the controller. The Nil suggests it's not getting the attribute from the known-good db. Going through through the controller by browser yields a manually-generated, old, record not generated by cucumber.

Comment: I changed my model to has_many :prices and altered the show to pull from @commodity.prices.each. I do see the two prices but the second is the first price again. retail_high +> '19'. I'm much closer now, but why two copies of the same price? Thank you for getting me this far.

Comment: Please, update your question with listings of related models, controllers and migrations.

Comment: First of all, clean your test database with `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`, then make sure that in the `features/support/env.rb` option `Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true` is set. I also believe that you don't use Selenium (for testing javascript) in this example. Finally, try the updated answer. You may want to add more fields to your factories as you have such thick models.

Comment: Thx, copying the above factory, step.rb and rerunning rake test yield the same duplicated result. The heavy model is needed. The question does not reflect every field for readability. Do not see the env.rb option described. Closest I have is "DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction". Should I manually add your env config line directly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8595/discussion-between-nash-bridges-and-sam452)